# Arrow keys not working in R running on Red Hat Server

Tags: r, bash, redhat

I am running R on a highperformance cluster running red hat.  When using R in interactive mode I get the typical untranslated key inputs when attempting to use the arrow keys.  Eg.  `^[[a`

Not exactly sure what is going on, especially since I am calling R while in a bash shell where the arrow keys work fine..

Comment: That is the behavior you get when starting R with `R --no-readline`.

Comment: How do you turn `--no-readline` off?  I am just calling R with the generic `$ R` or `$R --vanilla`

Comment: R will use readline (if available and enabled when the binary was built) by default. If readline is not working then either a) you've started R with the `--no-readline` option, b) readline is not available, c) R was configured/built with the `--with-readline=no` flag set. Bottom line, ask your sysadmin.

Comment: I asked and he was about as stumped as I was since readline is supposedly installed on all of our nodes.  On some of the nodes R 'works' correctly, on others it gives the untranslated inputs....  Thanks for pointing us in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ista tip in comment, my guess it that you have libreadline installed before installing R and readline is activated by default

See Appendix C in [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)

> **When the GNU readline library is available at the time R is configured
> for compilation under UNIX, an inbuilt command line editor allowing
> recall, editing and re-submission of prior commands is used.** Note that
> other versions of readline exist and may be used by the inbuilt
> command line editor: this used to happen on macOS.
>
> It can be disabled (useful for usage with ESS1 ) using the startup option --no-readline.